# How can I see if the certificate is SHA384?

Tags: openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

The client gave us the .pfx format of the certificate and we need to know if it is running on SHA384 or not. Is there any command in openssl for this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Certificates are inanimate. They don't "run" on anything. Can you explain what you mean? Single commands are generally not considered programming questions, they are better asked on e.g. superuser.

Comment: ah ok. i think we can see thru browser. anyway, the server team already answered. thank you.